# How to export kendo grid to excel with multi-lines in header cells

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, export-to-excel

I want two(or more) lines of text in the header cell. I am aware about making the text wrap visually in the grid but I will not always have long text and besides, the wrapped text doesn't export in multi lines to the excel worksheet either. I want the line break to be at specific positions in the text both visually in the grid and in the exported excel worksheet.

For example, in the example I provided, I would like to be able to strip out the `<br>` html during export and have the export create a multi-line header.

So if I had the following kendo-grid heading:

[image]

I would like the excel export to look like this:
[image]

Instead `<br>` is outputted:
[image]

Plunker here http://plnkr.co/edit/v3TYgA?p=preview

Plunker code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <base href="http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/excel-export">

  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.1.318/styles/kendo.common-material.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.1.318/styles/kendo.material.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.1.318/styles/kendo.dataviz.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.1.318/styles/kendo.dataviz.material.min.css" />

  <script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.1.318/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.1.318/js/jszip.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.1.318/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
    <style>
    html {
      font-size: 12px;
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }
    .k-grid-header .k-header {
      white-space: normal !important;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="example">
    <div id="grid" style="width: 900px"></div>
    <script>
      $("#grid").kendoGrid({
        toolbar: ["excel"],
        excel: {
          fileName: "Kendo UI Grid Export.xlsx",
          proxyURL: "http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/export",
          filterable: true
        },
        excelExport: (e) => {
        //let width for exported columns auto set
        e.workbook.sheets[0].columns.forEach((col) => {
                col.autoWidth = true;
            });

        },
        dataSource: {
          type: "odata",
          transport: {
            read: "http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Northwind.svc/Products"
          },
          schema: {
            model: {
              fields: {
                UnitsInStock: {
                  type: "number"
                },
                ProductName: {
                  type: "string"
                },
                UnitPrice: {
                  type: "number"
                },
                UnitsOnOrder: {
                  type: "number"
                },
                UnitsInStock: {
                  type: "number"
                }
              }
            }
          },
          pageSize: 7
        },
        sortable: true,
        pageable: true,
        columns: [ {
          width: "35%",
          field: "UnitPrice",
          title: "Unit Price and some very loooong text that will make this line wrap. Not what I am looking for. Plus it doesn't export in multilines either.",
        }, {
          width: "30%",
          field: "UnitsOnOrder",
          title: "Units On Order"
        }, {
          width: "35%",
          field: "UnitsInStock",
          title: "Units In Stock <br> (Excludes foreign)"
        }]
      });

    </script>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I deleted my answer pointing out using a header template as it did not work for you. Perhaps it is the <br> could you try the export using another way to add a break, perhaps a <div> with a clear-both style. I am not certain it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you will have better results using a header template instead:

```
columns:[{
            width: "35%",
            field: "UnitsInStock",
            title: "Units In Stock ",
            headerTemplate: "Units In Stock <br> (Excludes foreign)"   
        }]
```

Comment: Thanks. I have tried headerTemplate. It makes no difference when it comes to trying to create multi-lines. The exported worksheet still doesn't have multi-lines.

Answer (score 0):

If you want "`<br/>`" tags to work/execute like HTML in Kendo Grid, you need to use "column.encoded" property.
Official Documentation : https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/configuration/columns.encoded

There's a DOJO link on the page as well, that sets a really good example.